# Frontend in React/NodeJS with multiple backends user login

Tags: reactjs, node.js, authentication, security, architecture

I have a frontend implemented with React/Node that uses a monolithical backend.

Today, that backend is using Spring security to provide user login and authentication. Once user is authenticated, a cookie is provided to him and then he continues using that cookie.

But the backend will be splitted in 3 services: A, B and user service, that is able to tell if a user/pass pair is correct.

My idea is to just use an api key for A, B and user services and give to React/Node the cookies responsibility. So my question is, is this a good idea?

Otherwise (using Spring security in each service), I have to authenticate with each different service, which will ruin user experience in the app.

In case it is a good idea, is there some library in NodeJS implementing cookies in a database?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a React question as much as it is a question about your backend technology.  React certainly can make calls to APIs, get cookies, reply with them, etc.

Usually you would look to put all of your APIs at a common server (e.g. `/api/a`, `/api/b`, and `/api/userService`), and then have some type of higher-level construct that guards all APIs that require authentication. So you configure that auth-check in one place of your backend, and each API leverages that single configuration.

If your APIs are not sharing a common infrastructure (e.g. running on the same server/port), then you'll be required to do some type of auth-check for each one of them .... and it makes coding your React front end more painful as you now need to be tracking multiple servers not just multiple API endpoints on a single server.